# MATLAB GUI Guide Error with Map

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm trying to insert a map into MATLAB's GUI GUIDE and I'm getting the error:

> Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

The map does work when I run it standalone in the command window but when I push the button in GUIDE, it appears then gets distorted, and then I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
function temp_button_Callback(hObject,eventdata,handles)
lat = [80 45 52; 45 46 34]
long = [123 132 123; 120 122 119]
temp = [67 68 69; 71 72 73]

axesm('mercator','MapLatLimit',[-50 90],'MapLonLimit',[0 250])
framem on; gridm on;
load coast;
mlabel on;
plabel on;
plotm(lat,long,'k')


contourfm(long,lat,temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got `clear lat long;` right before `contourfm(long,lat,temp)`. Clearly you still need those variables, so don't clear them.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.  It runs perfectly as a script.

Comment: When plotting the first time on the screen the plot appears but when I push another push button it plots that plot on top of the previous plot.